# Spring Transactional context wrapping?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using spring/hibernate. I have service layer and DAO layer. Transactions are placed in Service layer.
I have FirstServiceImpl class. In one of the method of FirstServiceImpl class it has 500 lines of code. what I did was I took all 500 lines of code and placed in a separate class(wrote one interface and implementation class. In the FirstServiceImpl class I autowired newly created interface to access its single method). 
I placed @Transactional on FirstServiceImpl class.

My question is "does the newly created class logic also runs in Transactional context"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure but I think it will use [transaction propagation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-propagation). But I can tell you sure way to test whether it works or not.

Do following database operation through your code in single transaction.

> Insert/update one row into db, try to insert/update second row in the same transaction.
>
> While inserting second row intentionally raise an exception. If you can see "first entry" in database, that means your transaction is not rolled back. And it does not work.
>
> While if there is no first row entry in database, that means your transaction is rolled back. Here you may get **UnexpectedRollbackException**.

Before testing make sure your annotation is `@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)`